# Make CONSTRAINT with string and integer in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am a beginner. I created a query on PostgreSQL. I want to make CONSTRAINT with string and integer. It was successfully running but when I insert the data, it gave me an error

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
    id_customer char(5) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT cek_id_customer CHECK ((left(id_customer,2) in ('CU')) 
                                      and  substring(id_customer,3) LIKE '%[0-9]%'), 
    nama_customer varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    gender_customer varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT  cek_gender_customer CHECK(gender_customer = 'Male' OR gender_customer = 'Female')
);

INSERT INTO customer 
VALUES ('CU001', 'Sayaa', 'Male')
```

The message

ERROR:  new row for relation "customer" violates check constraint "cek_id_customer"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (CU001, Sayaa, Male).
SQL state: 23514

Comment: Please do not use images for textual information. Add the error message to your question as copy and paste text.

Comment: What's the error? That like only guarantees a single digit by the way.

Comment: Are you sure the constraint actually matches what's posted above?

Comment: Unrelated, but: [Don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: Hi, I wrote the message above. thank you

Comment: `LIKE` does not support regular expressions in SQL. You need to use Postgres' `~` operator or `similar to` if you want to check for character ranges

Answer (score 1):

To enforce the matching pattern you want you can use a regular expression matching rule in the constraint, like `id_customer ~ '^CU[0-9]*$'`.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  id_customer char(5) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT cek_id_customer CHECK (id_customer ~ '^CU[0-9]*$'),
  nama_customer varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  gender_customer varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT cek_gender_customer CHECK(
    gender_customer = 'Male' OR
    gender_customer = 'Female'
  )
);

INSERT INTO customer (id_customer, nama_customer, gender_customer)
VALUES ('CU001', 'Sayaa', 'Male'); -- succeeds

INSERT INTO customer (id_customer, nama_customer, gender_customer)
VALUES ('CU1X', 'Sayaa', 'Male'); -- fails!
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dmkiABRNziqP9ubxGqyk5V/0).

Comment: A somewhat stronger check would be `CHECK (id_customer ~ '^CU[0-9]{3}$')` . This requires 'CU' followed by *exactly* 3 digits.